# How to add bookmarkt to UITableView Cell & save to CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, cloudkit

I have a question on adding bookmark/favorite button to a UITableView. Currently my mainVC has a tableView that is populated from a public database in CloudKit. If I want to add a bookmark/favorite button where the user can save the data for that row into CoreData (string objects, image, boolean type)...how I do I execute that?

I added the button as an outlet to UITableViewCell. In the cellForRow, I added

```
cell.favoriteButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then I added a @IBAction addFavorites to that MainVC, but I'm unsure how do I save all the objects to CoreData from that row?

This is my save to Core Data method:

```
if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext
{
   place = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Place", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Place
   place.name = name!
   place.type = type!
   place.address = address!
   place.neighborhood = neighborhood!
   place.phoneNumber = phoneNumber!
   if let placeImage = imageView.image
   {
      place.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(placeImage)
   }
   do {
      try managedObjectContext.save()
   } catch {
      print(error)
      return
   }
```

Any advice?

Comment: Why don't you use parse.com for saving the objects?

Answer (score 0):

First, I think using tags is not a very good idea. To identify a row with a button use this method:

```
let point = button.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: tableView)
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)!
```

Second, where are you getting your variables from? In your code it looks like you are using properties associated with the cell. That is also not a good idea because you should not use the view to read your data - instead use the original CloudKit data source.

Third, it is not advisable to store an image in Core Data unless it is just a small thumbnail. If it is larger, use external storage, devise a scheme in your application documents folder or download on demand from CloudKit.

Finally, it is not clear what else you need. I suppose you want to display the favorite status in the table view. If you could include some kind of unique identifier, you could check the existence of this identifier in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your Core Data set of objects and mark the cell accordingly.